# Islamic principals when patterning with a marketing firm that Markets products in a haram way?

Tags: business

I own a Social Media Marketing Firm and my question is if I refer my client to one of my peers marketing firm, they will market the product in a haram way. I will be receiving commission for partnering them together. Will it be haram partnering them together?